# Как сделать появление блока при наведении или нажатию на иконку?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как сделать появление блока при наведении или нажатию на иконку?

Код окна с иконкой:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/alexshev07/85pvxzog/2/
```

```css
.picker-block {
  max-width: 220px;
}


/*окно с текстом и цветам*/

.popup-window {
  background: rgb(190, 231, 209);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/*треугольник*/

.popup-window:after {
  content: '';
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid rgb(190, 231, 209);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  bottom: -24px;
  width: 0;
}


/*Круг в котором иконка*/

.round-popup {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*Иконка*/

.fa-fill-drip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}


/*Флекс режим*/

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*Цветные блоки*/

.red-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="picker-block">
      <div class="popup-window d-flex">
        <div class="red-block"></div>
        <div class="green-block"></div>
        <div class="blue-block"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Выберите цвет!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="round-popup">
        <i class="fas fa-fill-drip" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript (jQuery) в помощь.

При клике:

```js
$(".round-popup").click(function() {
  if ($(".d-flex").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".d-flex").slideDown("slow").css({
      display: "flex"
    });
  } else {
    $(".d-flex").slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
}

.picker-block {
  max-width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*окно с текстом и цветам*/

.popup-window {
  background: rgb(190, 231, 209);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/*треугольник*/

.popup-window:after {
  content: '';
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid rgb(190, 231, 209);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  bottom: -24px;
  width: 0;
}


/*Круг в котором иконка*/

.round-popup {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Иконка*/

.fa-fill-drip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}


/*Флекс режим*/

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: none;
}

.round-popup:hover~.d-flex {
  display: block;
}


/*Цветные блоки*/

.red-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="picker-block">
      <div class="popup-window d-flex">
        <div class="red-block"></div>
        <div class="green-block"></div>
        <div class="blue-block"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Выберите цвет!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="round-popup">
        <i class="fas fa-fill-drip" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При наведении:

```js
$(".round-popup").hover(function() {
  if ($(".d-flex").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".d-flex").slideDown("slow").css({
      display: "flex"
    });
  } else {
    // $(".d-flex").slideUp("slow");
  }
  $(function() {
    $(".container").hover(onIn, onOut);
  });
  function onIn() {
    $(this).css({
      display: "flex"
    });
  }
  function onOut() {
    $(".d-flex").slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
}

.picker-block {
  max-width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*окно с текстом и цветам*/

.popup-window {
  background: rgb(190, 231, 209);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/*треугольник*/

.popup-window:after {
  content: '';
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid rgb(190, 231, 209);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  bottom: -24px;
  width: 0;
}


/*Круг в котором иконка*/

.round-popup {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Иконка*/

.fa-fill-drip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}


/*Флекс режим*/

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: none;
}

.round-popup:hover~.d-flex {
  display: block;
}


/*Цветные блоки*/

.red-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue-block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="picker-block">
      <div class="popup-window d-flex">
        <div class="red-block"></div>
        <div class="green-block"></div>
        <div class="blue-block"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Выберите цвет!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="round-popup">
        <i class="fas fa-fill-drip" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: d-flex - флексом сделай при клике

Comment: @Sevastopol' при наведении не работает, и элементы выстроились в столбец, это наверное из-а display-block

Comment: Вот теперь круто, спс) только при наведении всё равно не пашет...

Comment: я плюсик поставил

Comment: @Sevastopol' буду благодарен, если добавите ещё при наведении чтобы работало

Comment: @Sevastopol' не могли бы подсказать ещё ко-что, встраиваю этот всплывающий блок на сайт справа внизу, когда кликаю на него, сама иконка прыгает вниз и потом раскрывается, почему, как это исправить можно, может вы сразу увидите в чём ошибка..? https://retris.ru/

Answer (score 3):

Только CSS, только хардкор..

При наведение:

```css
.change-color {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* --- */
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.change-color .icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  padding: 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-color .droped {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #bee7d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 220px / 2); /* или left: -50%; transform: translateX(-50%);*/
  bottom: calc(30px + 10px);
}

.change-color .droped::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #bee7d1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.change-color .droped .select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.change-color .droped .select .item {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.change-color:hover .droped {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="change-color">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-fill-drip"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="droped">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="item" style="background: red;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: green;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Выберите цвет!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

При клике:

```css
.change-color {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* --- */
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.change-color .icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  padding: 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-color .droped {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #bee7d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 220px / 2); /* или left: -50%; transform: translateX(-50%);*/
  bottom: calc(30px + 10px);
}

.change-color .droped::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #bee7d1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.change-color .droped .select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.change-color .droped .select .item {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#change_color:checked ~ .droped {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="change-color">
  <input type="checkbox" id="change_color" style="display: none;">
  <label class="icon" for="change_color">
    <i class="fas fa-fill-drip"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="droped">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="item" style="background: red;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: green;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Выберите цвет!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## С плавной анимацией

**Важно!**
В примерах используется [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), ознакомьтесь с его [поддержкой](https://caniuse.com/pointer-events).

При наведение:

```css
.change-color {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* --- */
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.change-color .icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  padding: 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-color .droped {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #bee7d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 220px / 2); /* или left: -50%; transform: translateX(-50%);*/
  /* anim */
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.change-color .droped::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #bee7d1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.change-color .droped .select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.change-color .droped .select .item {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.change-color:hover .droped {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: calc(30px + 10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="change-color">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-fill-drip"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="droped">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="item" style="background: red;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: green;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Выберите цвет!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

При клике:

```css
.change-color {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* --- */
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.change-color .icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  padding: 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-color .droped {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #bee7d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 220px / 2); /* или left: -50%; transform: translateX(-50%);*/
  
  /* anim */
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.change-color .droped::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #bee7d1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.change-color .droped .select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.change-color .droped .select .item {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#change_color:checked ~ .droped {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: calc(30px + 10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="change-color">
  <input type="checkbox" id="change_color" style="display: none;">
  <label class="icon" for="change_color">
    <i class="fas fa-fill-drip"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="droped">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="item" style="background: red;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: green;"></div>
      <div class="item" style="background: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Выберите цвет!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexfixer, добавил варианты с анимацией

Comment: Круто!, благодарю.)